# Embedding Quotes in PHP

Tags: php

I need to do a triple embedding of quotes into PHP in order to execute a javascript command correctly and I was wondering if there was any way to do this.
For example, the thing I'm trying to triply embed is

```
echo ("<tr id='regular' onMouseOver='highlight($emp,$job,$cust,$lat,$lng)' onMouseOut='unhighlight()'>
                    <td>$emp</td>
                    <td>$job</td>
                    <td>$cust</td>
                    <td>$lat</td>
                    <td>$lng</td>
                   </tr>\n");
```

The thing is that I need to put in '$emp', '$job', and '$cust', but whenever I put those in it ends the onMouseOver right after the first `<td>`.

Comment: Ever heard of HEREDOC strings?

Comment: Wow really fast answers, all of which are excellent, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really nest single quotes within single quotes that way. The easiest solution is to use escaped double quotes.

```
echo ("<tr id='regular' onMouseOver='highlight(\"$emp\",\"$job\",\"$cust\",\"$lat\",\"$lng\")' onMouseOut='unhighlight()'>
                    <td>$emp</td>
                    <td>$job</td>
                    <td>$cust</td>
                    <td>$lat</td>
                    <td>$lng</td>
                   </tr>\n");
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape quotes using the the backslash `\` character.

Here is an example

```
echo "\"Daniel\"";
```

Will print `"Daniel"` with the quotes

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php for more information

Answer (score 2):

[HEREDOCS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)!

```
echo <<<HTML
<tr id="regular" onMouseOver="highlight('$emp','$job','$cust','$lat','$lng')" onMouseOut="unhighlight()">
  <td>$emp</td>
  <td>$job</td>
  <td>$cust</td>
  <td>$lat</td>
  <td>$lng</td>
</tr>
HTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but I'll give it a shot:

- To embed quotes inside a string (with quotes), you need to escape them, so that you can do something like:

  ```
  $string = "This is a string, and those: \"are quotes\"";
  ```
- To embed variables inside a string without quirks, try using the curly brackets `{}`:

  ```
  $string = "onMouseOver='highlight({$emp},{$job},{$cust},{$lat},{$lng})'";
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
echo ('<tr id="regular" onMouseOver="highlight(\'$emp\', \'$job\', \'$cust\', \'$lat\', \'$lng\');" onMouseOut="unhighlight();">');
    echo ("<td>$emp</td>");
    echo ("<td>$job</td>");
    echo ("<td>$cust</td>");
    echo ("<td>$lat</td>");
    echo ("<td>$lng</td>");
echo ("</tr>\n");
```

The `\` character escapes the `'` from effecting the string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the ' character.

```
echo ("<tr id='regular' onMouseOver='highlight(\'$emp\',\'$job\',\'$cust\',\'$lat\',\'$lng\')' onMouseOut='unhighlight()'>
                    <td>$emp</td>
                    <td>$job</td>
                    <td>$cust</td>
                    <td>$lat</td>
                    <td>$lng</td>
                   </tr>\n");
```